# throw new Error('Missing PFX or certificate + private key')

Tags: node.js, express, https, pfx, node.js-connect

I have previously developed a module in node.js and after complete testing I put it in Github. Now I downloaded the zipped version of the same module from Github and I tried to run the module, installing all the dependencies, but now I am getting the following error:

```
 Error:Missing PFX + certificate + private key
```

The complete Error Log is as follows:

```
       Error: Missing PFX or certificate + private key.
              at HTTPSServer.Server (tls.js:1029:11)
              at HTTPSServer.Server (https.js:35:14)
              at HTTPSServer (C:/Social/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/https.js:34:16)
              at new HTTPSServer (C:/Social/node_modules/express/lib/https.js:38:23)
              at Object.exports.createServer (C:/Social/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:43:12)
              at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Social/app.js:46:36)
              at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
              at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
              at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
              at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I tried to find the solution but I could not find any. Can anyone help me to with the same?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't include the required HTTPS files (key and certificate) in your module (which is probably a good thing, since they don't belong in a public repo, but they are still requirements that have to be added *somehow*).

Comment: i downloaded it as i download any other module and it never gave me such error. it is for the first time i am getting this error. i never used any https before( key and certificate )

Comment: I don't know the reason behind putting a negative point on the question!!!!

Comment: Well, you're not posting a lot of information. If your project is on Github, post a link to it so others can try it.

Comment: Here is the link.....     https://github.com/pragtech/Social-Networking-Site-in-Node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, Express thinks you want to start an HTTPS server. My guess would be this is because of this line in your code:

```
var app = module.exports = express.createServer(form({ keepExtensions: true }));
```

([link](https://github.com/pragtech/Social-Networking-Site-in-Node.js/blob/master/app.js#L44))

However, Express uses this code to see if it should start an HTTPS server:

```
exports.createServer = function(options){
  if ('object' == typeof options) {
    return new HTTPSServer(options, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  } else {
    return new HTTPServer(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  }
};
```

Which is a bit strange, since `form()` returns a function and not an object. But to be sure, try rewriting your code to this:

```
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();
app.use(form({ keepExtensions: true }));
```